# What is the storage limit of the Blast Mine sack in Oldschool RuneScape?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In the Blast Mine all the ores you collect are deposited in the sack. At the top of the screen is a counter of how many ores you collected of each type. I wonder how many ores you can store in the sack before you can't store any more and are forced to collect them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [wiki](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Blast_mine):

**When there are 450 of any single type of ore in the sack, it will become full and the player will need to collect it...**